# azure pipelines Yaml merging parameters object

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to merging object parameters in azure pipeline: the goal is to setup a list of environment variable containing URLs and inject them after as env var of a task;
the "thing" is that there are some preset that we want as already defined and we want to let the possibility to overwrite any variable from one preset if necessary

```
  - name: case
    type: string
    values:
      - case1
      - case2
  - name: vars
    type: object
    default:
      case1:
         FOO: bar
         API_URL: https://xxxx
         NAME: case1
      case2:
         FOO: bar2
         API_URL: https://xxxxyyyy
         NAME: case2
  - name: overwritten_var
    type: object
    default: []
```

the problems is that variables should be set up dynamically

I tried to use setvariable as workaround to merge, with:

```
  - ${{ each var in parameters.vars[parameters.case] }}:
     - script: "echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=${{ var.Key }}]${{ var.Value }} "
```

which worked correctly.
and it allowed me to override with

```
  - ${{ each var in parameters.vars[parameters.overwrited_var] }}:
     - script: "echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=${{ var.Key }}]${{ var.Value }} "
```

But when I try on inject it in a task as env var the variables are not evaluated in runtime

```
- task: Bash@3
  name: "Runtest"
  inputs:
  targetType: "inline"
  script: |
    env
  env:
   ${{ each var in parameters.vars[parameters.case] }}:
     ${{ var.Key }}: $[variables.${{ var.Key }}]
```

it gives the following result at execution:

```
FOO=$[variables.FOO]
```

any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. You are mixing type of evaluation.

Runtime parameters uses expression syntax `${{}}` which is evaluated at compile this. This is why these parts works

```
 - ${{ each var in parameters.vars[parameters.case] }}:
     - script: "echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=${{ var.Key }}]${{ var.Value }} "
```

```
 - ${{ each var in parameters.vars[parameters.overwrited_var] }}:
     - script: "echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=${{ var.Key }}]${{ var.Value }} "
```

But this doesn't work because you mix here compile time and runtime syntax.

```
- task: Bash@3
  name: "Runtest"
  inputs:
  targetType: "inline"
  script: |
    env
  env:
   ${{ each var in parameters.vars[parameters.case] }}:
     ${{ var.Key }}: $[variables.${{ var.Key }}]
```

But the whole expression is evaluated at compile time and runtime expression is considered as string literal. This is why you get this output

```
FOO=$[variables.FOO]
```

This is not evaluated again in next round.

This is not possible to perform. Simply values/variables used in compile time have to be known at compile time.

Comment: yes that's what i figured out 
(i was hoping the runtime evaluation was still applied) there is a another way to merging object?

Comment: It is not possible to merge objects which part is compile time and part runtime.

Comment: @quentin ledoux, Regarding your issue, Krzysztof gave a very good explanation. In order to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept the answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!

Comment: hello yes the answer is really good for explaining why the workaround are not working  but not how to do an another workaround (maybe more dirty) to achieve the initial problem that's why i wait a little bit to see if someone give another answer. because of no answer i validate it :)